# How to enable restkit logging in swift

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

In iOS I can enable restkit logging with:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network*", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

But, I can't find a solution to do the same in Swift

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here

```
 RKlcl_configure_by_name("RestKit/Network", RKlcl_vTrace.rawValue);
 RKlcl_configure_by_name("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKlcl_vOff.rawValue);
```

Comment: Actually, you are going to have to use .rawValue instead of .value, at least I had to.

Comment: `rawValue` instead of `value`

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 2.2:**

```
RKlcl_configure_by_name("RestKit/Network", RKlcl_vTrace.rawValue);
RKlcl_configure_by_name("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKlcl_vOff.rawValue);
```